# mysql Order by column1 but if column2 = 0 then add to end but still order by column 1

Tags: mysql

I have a products table, i would like to list the products by name but if the stock level is 0 put them last but preferably ordered by name aswell.

```
id name quantity
1   aa     0 
2   ba     12
3   ac     66
4   ab     0
```

so the result i would like is

```
id name quantity
3   ac     66
2   ba     12    
1   aa     0 
4   ab     0
```

many thanks

Comment: ORDER BY quantity = 0,name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table order by quantity = 0, name
```

Should do you